how to setup multidomain on same WP setup with only different home page?
we have a WordPress site that is running fine, now we are planning to make it multilingual, and multidomain. One domain for each language, apart from the home page rest of the pages will be in English (default language), only the home will be different for each domain and in different languages.
like - the current domain is xyz.com showing the home page in English and abc.com will redirect to the same site but will show a different home page in a different language.
Can anyone please guide how we can set it up?
Thanks

https://wordpress.org/plugins/weglot/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=450111908&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAjwkJm0BhBxEiwAwT1AXPTJcyxcCN1xJYnszEgJ0BDZOI56Oqx4YKUOF3WCCxi08PFTU1MzCBoCw1AQAvD_BwE

As per your requirement I suggest you to use WPML plugin which has the similar feature you are looking for.
The first step is to Install WPML plugin, and for installation you need to purchase and download WPML from their official website and once you activate this plugin please configure WPML Languages by going to WPML > Languages in your WordPress admin dashboard.
Here you can choose the languages you want to support. For example, English (default) and another language like German. Then configure Language URL Format by going to WPML > Languages > Language URL format, here you need to choose "Different languages in directories" or "A different domain per language" option. Please Select "A different domain per language" for your setup as per your need.

WordPress actually has a nice build-in feature for this: WP Multi Site
https://developer.wordpress.org/advanced-administration/multisite/create-network/
It offers several options including subdomains for your network.
